# Understanding Miller Rabin implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, cryptography

I'm learning about Miller Rabin, and I'm looking at the following implementation of the algorithm from https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Mathematics/Primality_Testing#Java

I feel like I have an okay understanding of the algorithm, but the implementation is not very easy to follow mainly because of the lack of documentation. It would be very helpful if someone could walk through the code and explain what we're doing at each step, and why. Referencing the algorithm would be very helpful.

```
Algorithm:
Input: n > 3, an odd integer to be tested for primality; 
Input: k, a parameter that determines the accuracy of the test
Output: composite if n is composite, otherwise probably prime
write n − 1 as 2s·d with d odd by factoring powers of 2 from n − 1
LOOP: repeat k times:
   pick a randomly in the range [2, n − 2]
   x ← a^d mod n
   if x = 1 or x = n − 1 then do next LOOP
   for r = 1 .. s − 1
      x ← x^2 mod n
      if x = 1 then return composite
      if x = n − 1 then do next LOOP
      return composite
   return probably prime
```

Implentation:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

import java.util.Random;

public class MillerRabin {

    private static final BigInteger ZERO = BigInteger.ZERO;
    private static final BigInteger ONE = BigInteger.ONE;
    private static final BigInteger TWO = new BigInteger("2");
    private static final BigInteger THREE = new BigInteger("3");

    public static boolean isProbablePrime(BigInteger n, int k) {
        if (n.compareTo(THREE) < 0)
            return true;
        int s = 0;
        BigInteger d = n.subtract(ONE); // n-1
        while (d.mod(TWO).equals(ZERO)) { //?
            s++;                          //?
            d = d.divide(TWO);            //?
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {    //LOOP: repeat k times
            BigInteger a = uniformRandom(TWO, n.subtract(ONE)); //?
            BigInteger x = a.modPow(d, n);  //x = a^d mod n
            if (x.equals(ONE) || x.equals(n.subtract(ONE))) // if x=1 or x = n-1, then do next LOOP
                continue;
            int r = 1;
            for (; r < s; r++) { // for r = 1..s-1
                x = x.modPow(TWO, n);  //x = x ^ 2 mod n 
                if (x.equals(ONE))     //if x = 1, return false (composite
                    return false; 
                if (x.equals(n.subtract(ONE))) //if x= n-1, look at the next a
                    break;
            }
            if (r == s) // None of the steps made x equal n-1.
                return false; //we've exhausted all of our a values, probably composite
        }
        return true; //probably prime
    }

    //this method is just to generate a random int
    private static BigInteger uniformRandom(BigInteger bottom, BigInteger top) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        BigInteger res;
        do {
            res = new BigInteger(top.bitLength(), rnd);
        } while (res.compareTo(bottom) < 0 || res.compareTo(top) > 0);
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: What part of the code do you have a particular problem with?  Do you understand the pseudocode?  Try matching each line of pseudocode to the corresponding lines of code.

Comment: Hi @rossum thanks for the response and the suggestion to work through the code and match pseudeocode. I added comments with question marks on the lines I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of the code

```
    while (d.mod(TWO).equals(ZERO)) { //?
        s++;                          //?
        d = d.divide(TWO);            //?
    }
```

corresponds to

```
write n − 1 as 2^s·d with d odd by factoring powers of 2 from n − 1
```

As long as `d` is even, it is divided by 2 and `s` is incremented. After the loop `d` must be odd and `s` holds the number of factors 2 in `n-1`.

And this part

```
BigInteger a = uniformRandom(TWO, n.subtract(ONE)); //?
```

implements

```
pick a randomly in the range [2, n − 2]
```

Comment: WRT the random pick, Schneier suggests always starting with 2 since that is most likely to cause the rejection of a composite.  After that first pass, pick randomly from [3 .. n - 2].  It should generate a slight speedup.  Also the k parameter represents powers of 4 in the certainty, so for less than 1 in 2^128 chance of passing a composite as prime, pick k = 64.

Comment: @rossum for the chance of error, the 1/4 per iteration is what has been proven. For large numbers empirical data suggests, that the test is much better than that in practice. But of course, one cannot be sure ...